# How can I link an HTML file in a different directory to JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

This is the structure of my program. I wish to link HTML file from different directory into my JavaScript. Those html files are written with seperately functions.I wish to link into the script, making the `index.html` a multipurpose webpage. :

[image: program structure]

The code in my JavaScript is `let var1= "../../../traffic_switch/traffic_switch.html"`, but it doesn't work. What should I do？

Comment: Try changing the name of the variable. Javascript doesn't like it when you name variables after keywords.

Comment: I tried, but still doen't work in the way

Comment: Can you clarify what exactly you're trying to do?  Setting a javascript variable to the path to an html file just gives you a variable containing a string.

Comment: Your question says you want to link HTML into JavaScript. I'm not sure what that means. The comment above says the opposite. Please clarify your question. Also update to remove `var` as a variable name to avoid distraction.

Comment: I am going to link script to multiple seperately html files with contain different functions. Combining them into index.html, becoming an entire webpage

Comment: Sounds like a job for [`Fetch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch).

Comment: So how can I use Fetch when I wish to declare the path to a variable?

Comment: Remember, Javascript runs in the browser on the client, therefore does not have host directory access. Fetch can be used to retrieve documents from the server, and the path in your question ought to work just fine. Show an example of your Javascript code that is trying to add an HTML file to the page, so someone can suggest a solution appropriate to your needs.

Comment: Does this article help? [How To Get HTML Content With Javascript Fetch](https://code-boxx.com/get-html-content-javascript-fetch/)

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to add a script to your HTML file?

If so then you will need to add this to the head of your traffic_switch.html file:

`<script src="../Camera/static/js/config.js"></script>`

Comment: No, I'm just want to link my script to html file which is seperatly functional. The script will wish to link with others html file too. The html file won't use any of the script.

Answer (score -1):

Change road_switch for traffic_switch:

```
let path = "../../../traffic_switch/traffic_switch.html"
```